# jQuery scroll page so cursor stays at the "logical center"

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a huge html form , with near 350 controls that take 5-6 times of the user screen height.
user starts completing each input field from the beginning of the page and goes on.
once the cursor rich near the bottom of screen user must be able to see some next input fields so here is the problem : 
i want to avoid the scrollbar usage.
i want to set some "margines" ( say 200px for each page side )

if user clicks a control that is near the screen edge, here this mechanism must work also

i'm looking for a jQuery solution

playing around with jQuery.ScrollTo, but can't figure out how to embed my logic into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

http://jsfiddle.net/JsWnk/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').focus(function() {

        var padding = 100; // Desired page "padding"

        var lbound = $(this).offset().top - $(window).height() + padding;
        var ubound = $(this).offset().top - padding;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < lbound)
            $(window).scrollTop(lbound);
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ubound)
            $(window).scrollTop(ubound);

    });
});
​
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for.
with a little tweak it should behave the same for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

http://jsfiddle.net/q9QHQ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').focus(function() {

        if ($(this).offset().top > 100)
            $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top + 100);

    });
});
```

Comment: there is a little problem here, the cursor stays out of the active window except if you write something